# Create Typescript object delete json data

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

When creating an object from a json, part of the json is deleted.

The original json has the following values:

```
error = {
    "Status": 0,
    "Code": 200,
    "Message": "",
    "Data": {
        "Id": 2326,
        "IdUsuario": 2,
        "Adenda": {
            "Id": 2326,
            "Texto": "",
            "CFE_Id": 0,
            "CamposDinamicos": []
        },
        "CAE": [],
        "DescuentoRecargo": [], 
        "CompFiscal": {
            "Id": 2326,
            "RUCEmisor": "aaaaa",
            "CodTipoDocMandante": 2,
            "CodigoPais": "UY",
            "NroDocMandante": "aaaa",
            "DenominacionMandante": "Complemento fiscal",
            "CFE_Id": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Now we create an object that receives this json in the constructor:

```
export class RespuestaAPI {
    public constructor(init?: Partial<RespuestaAPI>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
    Status: number;
    Code: HttpCode;
    Message: string;
    Data: any;
}
```

when we print the object created there is a missing part:

```
let r =  new RespuestaAPI(error.json());
console.log(r);
```

and the printed value is the following:

```
{
    "Status": 0,
    "Code": 200,
    "Message": "",
    "Data": {
        "Id": 2326,
        "IdUsuario": 2,
        "Adenda": {
            "Id": 2326,
            "Texto": "",
            "CFE_Id": 0,
            "CamposDinamicos": []
        },
        "CAE": [],
        "DescuentoRecargo": [], 
        "CompFiscal": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone) does a shallow copy of object properties.